# Matlab: Curve Fitting with Start Value

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I’m working with the Matlab Curve Fitting tool for the very first time and I have a question. My fit is exponential with two terms and it looks pretty good. The problem is, it won’t start from P(0,0), although my first measurement is.

Is it possible to force a start value onto my fit? Also, how does R-squared work? Is it safe to rely on?

Thank you so much

Comment: It is better to include a simplified version of your code here. You also should know that generally you can force the curve to pass all the points but you might end up overfitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a thorough description of this process [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94272-how-do-i-constrain-a-fitted-curve-through-specific-points-like-the-origin-in-matlab)

In short, the most common method of fitting to a polynomial in matlab, `polyfit`, does not allow for forcing through zero (or anywhere else), and so a different function is required, `lsqlin`, for example.